# Gulp doesn't generate index.html

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using the Gulp with the following settings:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb){
    del(['dist'], cb);
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    var injectAppFiles = gulp.src('src/styles/*.scss', {read: false});
    var injectGlobalFiles = gulp.src('src/global/*.scss', {read: false});

    function transformFilepath(filepath) {
        return '@import "' + filepath + '";';
    }

    var injectAppOptions = {
        transform: transformFilepath,
        starttag: '// inject:app',
        endtag: '// endinject',
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    var injectGlobalOptions = {
        transform: transformFilepath,
        starttag: '// inject:global',
        endtag: '// endinject',
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    return gulp.src('src/main.scss')
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(inject(injectGlobalFiles, injectGlobalOptions))
        .pipe(inject(injectAppFiles, injectAppOptions))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'styles'], function(){
    var injectFiles = gulp.src(['dist/styles/main.css']);

    var injectOptions = {
        addRootSlash: false,
        ignorePath: ['src', 'dist']
    };

    return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I expect to get dist/styles/main.css and dist/index.htm, but the second one doesn't generate. What can I do? Packets that I use: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-inject, bootstrap-sass (bower), wiredep, del

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: No. It runs without any error messages and warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem. I just removed a variable `cb` from the clean callback

```
gulp.task('clean', function(cb){
    del(['dist'], cb);
});
```

->

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    del(['dist']);
});
```